# Rails 3 Routing - specifying an exact controller from within a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm having a bit of a problem with route namespaces that I've not encountered before. This is actually a part of some gem development I'm doing - but i've reworked the problem to fit with a more generic rails situation.

Basically, I have a namespaced route, but I want it to direct to a generic (top-level) controller.

My controller is `PublishController`, which handles publishing of many different types of Models - which all conform to the same interface, but can be under different namespaces. My routes look like this:

```
# config/routes.rb

namespace :manage do
  resources :projects do
    get 'publish' => 'publish#create'
    get 'unpublish' => 'publish#destroy'
  end
end
```

The problem is that this creates the following routes:

```
manage_project_publish GET    /manage/projects/:project_id/publish(.:format)        {:controller=>"manage/publish", :action=>"create"}
manage_project_unpublish GET    /manage/projects/:project_id/unpublish(.:format)      {:controller=>"manage/publish", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Which is the routes I want, just not mapping to the correct controller. I've tried everything I can think of try and allow for the controller not to carry the namespace, but I'm stumped.

I know that I *could* do the following:

```
get 'manage/features/:feature_id/publish' => "publish#create", :as => "manage_project_publish"
```

which produces:

```
manage_project_publish GET    /manage/projects/:project_id/publish(.:format)        {:controller=>"publish", :action=>"create"}
```

but ideally, I'd prefer to use the nested declaration (for readability) - if it's even possible; which I'm starting to think it isn't.

Answer (score 14):

resource takes an optional hash where you can specify the controller so

```
resource :projects do
```

would be written as

```
resource :projects, :controller=>:publish do
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `scope` rather than `namespace` when you want a scoped route but not a controller within a module of the same name.

Comment: I had originally thought to do this too - but unfortunately, since this is actually to be packaged as a route helper method as part of a gem, I have no control over the wrapping method. Hence, why I was looking for a way to 'break out' of the current namespace.

Comment: and scope doesn't create named routes AFAIK

Comment: You can do that with `as: :blah` on the end of the scope.

Comment: If I could upvote this again, I would. This is pretty scarce knowledge in-context.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correct, you want this:

```
scope :manage do
  resources :projects, :only => [] do
    get 'publish' => 'publish#create'
    get 'unpublish' => 'publish#destroy'
  end
end
```

to poduce these routes:

```
project_publish     GET    /projects/:project_id/publish(.:format)    {:action=>"create", :controller=>"publish"}
project_unpublish   GET    /projects/:project_id/unpublish(.:format)  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"publish"}
```

Am I understanding your need correctly? If so, this is what Ryan is explaining.

Comment: You're right, `scope` is perfect for this case where you want the URL to be scoped but the controller to not be in a URL.

Comment: Thanks William, I could've sworn I tried this at the time - but I'll have to dig up the project and take a look.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is this:

```
namespace :manage, module: nil do
  resources :projects do
    get 'publish' => 'publish#create'
    get 'unpublish' => 'publish#destroy'
  end
end
```

This does create the named routes as you wish(manage_projects...) but still call the controller `::Publish`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but for anyone still struggling with this, you can add a leading slash to the controller name to pull it out of any existing namespace.

```
concern :lockable do
  resource :locks, only: [] do
    post "lock" => "/locks#create"
    post "unlock" => "/locks#destroy"
  end
end
```

Now if you include that concern anywhere (either namespaced or not) you will always hit the LocksController.